# tiles selections

Tags: combinatorics

Joe has 9 tiles lettered C,O,P,Y,R,I,G,H,T.

Find the number of ways to select 4 tiles if the 4 tiles consists of either 'O' or 'I' but not both.

My answer:

(total number of ways to select 4 tiles from the 9) - (total number of ways to select both O and I)

$$\binom{9}{4} - [2\times \binom{7}{2}] = 84$$

The correct answer should be 70. What have I done incorrectly? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't got your sum right. $\binom94$ also counts tiles with neither O or I, so these need to be subtracted. Also you remove two lots of O and I - you only need to remove them once.

So you should have written

$$\binom94-\binom74-\binom72=70$$.

Alternatively, pick O or I and three others from the seven remaining legit tiles.

$$\binom73+\binom73=70$$